# error mounting /mnt/affe26f1-c669-4794-9015-7aff45393795

Tags: mount

i get an error message when I booted after changing a mounting option for a partition

> /mnt/affe26f1-c669-4794-9015-7aff45393795 is not ready or not present

i tried with

> mount errors=remount -ro /dev/sda/mnt/affe26f1-c669-4794-9015-7aff45393795

kindly give a solution

Comment: Which partition are you trying to mount?

Comment: mounting error appears for all partitions other than /home/

Comment: post the output of `lsblk` command.

Comment: please post the output in pastebin.com and provide the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gF83AaKc

Comment: which partition are you trying to mount?

Comment: i m trying to mount sda1 and sda5 t

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands to mount `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda5` partitions,

```
sudo mkdir /media/sda1
sudo mkdir /media/sda5
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /media/sda5
```

Now your `sda1` and `sda5` partitions are mounted in `/media/sda1` and `/media/sda5` respectively.